# How to prevent new Section to start at new page when there is no space

Tags: vertical-alignment, page-breaking, sections-paragraphs

I really hate it and annoyed when I start a new long section (I just use \section*{Section Name} and there is no additional package I'm using), but it starts at a new page because the new section doesn't have enough space at the bottom of the page.

Is there a way to force a section to start at the bottom of the page (where it should start) instead of page breaking?

For example, if I have 3 paragraphs in a section, but only have space for the 1st paragraph, how can I prevent tex from starting the section at a new page? I want something like section title and paragraph 1 to stay at the bottom of the current page, and then paragraph 2 and 3 to go on the next page.

Comment: TeX is trying to avoid have the section title at the bottom of the page, but the text of the section not coming until the next page.  Are you saying that's the behavior you want?

Comment: For example, if I have 3 paragraphs in a section, but only have space for the 1st paragraph, how can I prevent tex from starting the section at a new page? I want something like section title, then paragraph 1 at the bottom of the current page, and then paragraph 2 and 3 on the next page.

Comment: by default latex will allow breaking in the paragraph it just prevents breaking after the section head or after the first line. so if there is room for a whole paragraph but it is still breaking early there is some code you have not shown affecting the page breaking

Comment: \documentclass{article}

\newcommand\tA{\stepcounter{enumi} \theenumi) Some text to fill out the space. }
\newcommand\tB{\tA\tA One two three four five six. \tA\tA\tA\tA\tA}
\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

Some intro \tB

\tB

\section*{A section}

\tB

Paragraph two \tB\tB

\section*{Another section}

some more text \tB

A second paragraph \tB

A third paragraph \tA\tA\tA\tA

\section*{A third  section}

Some more text \tB\tB

A second paragraph in this section  \tB

A third  paragraph in this section  \tB
\end{document}

Comment: the above document shows the third section action as you ask, with the heading and two lines of text at the bottom of the page, and the rest of the first paragraph and two following paragraphs on page 2. Please edit it to show the problem you are asking about and add to your question